# DateDiff function SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

How can I subtract 3 months from the `GETDATE()` function?

What I am trying to do is get the last day of the month 3 months prior to the current month. So if today is 10.22.2012 how can I subtract 3 months from the current date and print the last day of that month, so I am looking to get this date: 07.31.2012?

Here is what I have so far but it only prints the last day of previous month:

```
DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3,
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -4, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Not printing what I need. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Last day of the month 3 months prior to the current month

```
DATEADD(M,DATEDIFF(M,0,GETDATE())-2,0)-1
```

Comment: Neat trick, never thought to use date 0 as a handy start of month/year sentinel